# mysql import only missing rows

Tags: cmd, mysql

I'm looking for a way to restore my DB from a prior backup. However, the backup should not simply overwrite all existing records but instead add only the difference between current DB and the backup file. If no "non existent" records are stored in the backup, nothing should happen. The backups were made with mysqldump. Any clues?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` statements from the dump file. Change the `INSERT` statements to `INSERT IGNORE`. Then load the backup file and it should not update any duplicate rows.

Comment: Thanks, tried that but then then it simply stops updating the DB at all

Comment: Has the schema changed since the backup?

Comment: No, nothing changed. Tried with freshly made backups as well

Comment: I can't think of why INSERT IGNORE isn't working. It should skip the duplicates and insert all the rest.

Comment: Nevermind, it's working now. Was using JAVA to backup+restore and exceptions prevented the .sql file from being processed completely. Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

Here is a less manual answer:

`mysqldump -t --insert-ignore --skip-opt -u USER -pPASSWORD -h 127.0.0.1 database > database.sql`

That export command with the `-t --insert-ignore --skip-opt` options will give you a sql dump file with no `DROP TABLE` or `CREATE TABLE` commands and every `INSERT` is now an `INSERT IGNORE`.

***BONUS:***

This will dump a single table in the same way:

`mysqldump -t --insert-ignore --skip-opt -u USER -pPASSWORD -h 127.0.0.1 database table_name > table_name.sql`

I needed this today and could not help but to share it!